# Can we access react component once bundle it?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

**Steps:**

- I have many custom components. Hence, I created standalone package.
- I did it bundle using webpack.
- Include that bundle file in HTML page using script tag.
- Now, I just want to use it in HTML page like below example, but I cant access it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html />
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"> </script>
  <script src="build.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/jsx">
        ReactDOM.render(<CustomButton />, document.getElementById('root'));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Is it possible to access component once bundle ?